# How to remove the current folder in Powershell?

Tags: powershell

I use the `Remove-Item -Recurse -Force` command to remove large folders since the method seems much faster that using the Windows explorer, but a path is required. After adding a "[open Powershell here" entry to the Windows context menu](https://www.howtogeek.com/165268/how-to-add-open-powershell-here-to-the-context-menu-in-windows/) being able to remove the current folder would make deleting sizable directories almost seamless.

[image: a Powershell window]

Comment: As you cannot delete the directory you are in you will need to set your location to a variable, then change directory and then delet the previous directory, the following should do what you want: `$CurrentDir = Get-Location; cd ..; Remove-Item $CurrentDir -Recurse -Force`

Comment: @CraftyB this sounds like an answer to me. Why not write one?

Comment: OK, you've shown us the window that appears, but not the command you type nor the error/result. Your question needs to be edited or no one can help you.

Comment: @KeithMiller: I've updated the question (albeit you answered), I'm asked for path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, save the current location, move up one level, delete saved location.

Verbose:

```
$Path = Get-Location | Select -expand Path
Set-Location ..
Remove-Item -LiteralPath $Path -Recurse -Force
```

Key-banger:

```
$p = (gl).Path
sl ..
ri -LiteralPath $p -r -Fo
```

Create a function with an alias & add it to your profile if you want a single command easily available:

```
@'
Function Remove-Location {
   $Path = Get-Location | Select -expand Path
   Set-Location ..
   Remove-Item -LiteralPath $Path -Recurse -Force
   Exit    
}
Set-Alias rl Remove-Location
'@ | Add-Content $PROFILE -Append
```

Then you can open **PowerShell** to any folder, type `rl`, and the folder will be removed.

Comment: I haven't tested the alias yet, but accepted based on the command. Is it possible to make the Powershell window close once finished?

Comment: Yes, simply add an `Exit` statement to the Function definiton. I'll edit my answer to include that.

Comment: @user598527 just keep in mind that the `exit` will always close your powershell window after you executed the command. I'd stick with writing exit yourself after you executed the command

Comment: The command seems to struggle at least with brackets `[]`.

Comment: Struggle??? Is there an error message?

Comment: @KeithMiller: No, no error message: https://i.stack.imgur.com/64oHM.png

Comment: See edited code. Now using `-LiteralPath`.

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to handle this easily within the console the following command will set the current directory to a variable and then change to the parent directory and delete the previous directory:

```
$CurrentDir = Get-Location; cd ..; Remove-Item $CurrentDir -Recurse -Force
```

If you are feeling a bit more adventurous you could add an entry to the context menu so you do not need to interact with the shell altogether:

**Only continue with this if you are confident in using the registry editor, making mistakes could have irreversible effects**

Run `RegEdit.exe` from the run box.

Navigate to `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\` in the Registry Editor

"Right Click" on the shell folder and click "New" -> "Key"

Enter a name for the new key for the extension to the context menu in my case I used `PSMenu`. (I would name it the same for the simplicity of following this).

When inside the new key you will see a value on the right named `(Default)`, double click into this and modify the "Value Data" to what you want it to appear as in the context menu in my case I have used `Delete folder using PowerShell` then click "OK".

Next to make the command only visible on shift + right-click you will need to create a new value. Whilst inside the new key right-click in the right pane and click "New" - "String Value", name this value as `Extended` and do not populate the "Value Data".

Do not close the registry editor but jump to desktop etc, now when you Shift + Right-Click you should see the new entry that you have just created, though this is currently not hooked up to a command.

To add the command to the context entry return back to Registry Editor and Navigate to the Key "PSMenu" (Or what ever you named it). Right-click on the key in the left pane and "click" "New" -> "Key" and name this `command`, now select this key. Again you should have only a single value in the right pane named `(Default)`, double click this and paste the following into the `Value Data`:

```
C:\\Windows\\system32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\powershell.exe -NoExit -Command Remove-Item -LiteralPath '%L' -Recurse -Force; Exit
```

Click "ok" and then exit Registry Editor, the context menu entry you have created should now work and delete the folder you Shift + Right-Click and select that entry on.